# Node JS Promise TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, nodes

I am getting error on controller file.
TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined

My model file contains

```
        function dbQuerynew(sql){
            return new Promise( ( resolve, reject ) => {
                db.query(sql,
                 (err, result) => {
                   if (err) {
                     return reject(err)
                   }
                   return resolve(result)
                });
              })
        }
    var Product = {
        checkIds: function(product_id){
                var id_exist = 0;
                var sql = "SELECT mid FROM table WHERE product_id = '" + product_id + "'";
                const results = dbQuerynew(sql)
                .then(results => {
                    Promise.all(results.map(myId =>{
                        if(myId.mid === 46){
                             id_exist = 1;
                        }
                    }))
                })
                .then(()=>{
                     return id_exist;
                });
            }
    }
```

My Controller File contains

```
    exports.checkIdsFromProducts = (request,response) => {
        let getData = request.body;
        var product_id = getData.product_id
            product.checkIds(product_id)
            .then(result => {
                console.log(result);
            })
    }
```

Comment: `checkIds` isn't returning anything. You almost certainly also need to return the `Promise.all`

Comment: `checkIds` supposed to return `results` back. And the first then has to return `id_exist` back.

Comment: When i `console.log(id_exist)` in model it returns my result. but printing in controller file getting error "TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined "